# How to convert invalid XML with special characters to JSON with Json.NET

Tags: c#, xml, json.net

There are already some posts on parsing XML to JSON, but I have not come across skipping validating XML and properly translating to JSON in C# yet.

I would like to translate (invalid) XML code to JSON using Json.NET. The XML contains special characters such as: 
Space in `<send to>`, slash in `<body/content>`, ! in `<!priority>`.

In C# the `XDocument.Parse(xmlString)` always validates the XML, therefore converting will throw an exception. Decoding/encoding using the `HtmlUtility` affects the XML tags < and > and I haven't been able to use it. How can I make this work?

Some sample code can be found below.

Input (string):

```
<root>
<message>
<send to>some@email.com</send to>
<body/content>This is a message!</body/content>
<!priority>high</!priority>
</message>
</root>
```

Expected output (string):

```
{
    "root": {
        "message": {
            "send to": "some@email.com",
            "body/content": "This is a message!",
            "!priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that isn't valid xml.... you might want to write your own parser.

Comment: I'm aware this is invalid XML, but it needs to be translated to the JSON output. Do you have recommendations how it can be converted properly with valid XML (to JSON)? (Output needs to stay the same, so with spaces, ! and slashes)

Comment: where did this format come from? does it have a parser else where?

Comment: It's one thing to "skip validating XML" (i.e. the odd unsupported entity here or there), and quite another to read something which blatantly violates the XML standard by having tags which contain characters that aren't allowed. The latter is going to be a hard sell even for something to manually wrap around `XmlReader`. You are certainly much, *much* better off fixing this slop at the source -- parsing this is far harder than generating it. If something is willing to spit out "not XML", it can probably be coaxed to spit out "just a list of key-value pairs please".

Comment: The name of [the library is Json.NET and is made by Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), not NewtonSoft.

Comment: Use regex (*ducks and runs*)...

Comment: Honestly, regex might be the best solution, assuming the invalid XML always follows this structure and the text content never contains XML characters like `<` and `>`.  Fixing whatever generated this XML would be preferred.

Comment: Might be indeed better to fix the source and have valid input (it comes from an old external system). The expected output (JSON) is unchangable. Is there a suggested way to translate these special characters properly from XML to JSON?

I'm trying to stay away from RegEx since I expect there will be more exceptions than I currently think.

Comment: The issue isn't "special characters", it's parsing the tags in the first place -- it looks like XML but isn't. The parser needs to see that `<body/content>` is one tag with an invalid name, for example, and not at all like `</content>`, which closes an element. As suggested, you can use regexes to match this if there's no nasty surprises like an element named `/root` or `>good luck!<`, or write your own little recursive descent parser, or use a series of `.Replace` calls to replace just the offending names if they're from a small list (then read the XML as usual, and generate JSON manually).

Comment: You could try SGML as a Swiss army knife for processing markup (using OpenSP which isn't .net, but at least running on Windows). SGML will be able to take care of `<send to>` in start-element tags (similar to how it deals with HTML's `<div selected>`), and might make sense of the  `<!priority ...` pseudo-processing instruction, and even of  `body/content` using element minimization idioms from the 1980's. But honestly, your input looks hopeless :(

Comment: Or perhaps JTokens like: <BODY_SPACE_TO> transformed to <BODY TO>?

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat this as "invalid XML", treat it as some proprietary syntax completely unrelated to XML. No XML tools are going to help you with this. You first need to define a grammar for the non-XML files, then you need to write a parser for that grammar. Having written that parser, you can either generate JSON direcly, or you can generate XML and use an off-the-shelf XML-to-JSON converter.

Alternatively, if you possibly can, stop using proprietary syntax and use standards such as XML and JSON instead. Most people did that 20 years ago, and saved themselves a lot of money in the process.